# Globally have access to session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Is it possible to use the `session` variable inside of an ordinary `.rb` file except from the controller?

I'm using this [facebook messenger rails gem](https://github.com/hyperoslo/facebook-messenger) to build a bot. All requests come to `app/bot/listen.rb`. In that `listen.rb` file:

```
require "facebook/messenger"
extend ActionView::Helpers # I need also the session
include Facebook::Messenger

Bot.on :message do |message|
  session[:demo] = 1
  puts "Your session number is: #{session[:demo]}"
end
```

> Module::DelegationError (ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper#session delegated to controller.session, but controller is nil: main)

Is it possible to store data in session from within that `listen.rb` file?

Answer (score 2):

The UserInfo module encapsulates reading and writing the User object from/to the Thread local. This module can then be mixed in with other objects for easy access.

```
module UserInfo
  def session
    Thread.session
  end

  def self.session=(session)
    Thread.session = session
  end
end
```

A before_filter set in the ApplicationController will be called before any action is called in any controller. You can take advantage of this to copy a value out of the HTTP session and set it in the Thread local:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_user

  protected
  # Sets the current user into a named Thread location so that it can be accessed by models and observers
  def set_user
    UserInfo.session = session[:user]
  end
end
```

At any point in a Model class that you need to have access to those values you can just mixin the helper module and then use its methods to access the data. In this final example we mixin the UserInfo module to our model and it will now have access to the current_user method:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserInfo

  after_update :log_audit_change

  private
  def log_audit_change
    Audit.audit_change(current_user, self.id, self.new_balance)
  end
end
```